# How to set the creation time for the WSE 3.0 UsernameToken

Tags: c#, wse3.0, usernametoken

I'm using the WSE 3.0 UsernameToken to communicate with a network camera. Due the time difference between my PC and the network camera I can't authenticate, the allowed time difference is +- 5 sec UTC time, my current difference is 59 minutes and 19 seconds. The problem is that when I create the UsernameToken instance, the Created property is already set, and it's read only.

`var token = new UsernameToken(Username, Password, PasswordOption.SendHashed);`

I've tried to change manually the **xmlelement** generated by the UsernameToken instance to correct the time gap, but keep getting  **error 400**.

`XmlElement securityToken = token.GetXml(new XmlDocument());
securityToken.ChildNodes[3].InnerText = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");`

Comment: Are you aware that WSE is extremely obsolete and unsupported? And that it's not related to WCF?

Comment: I know it now thanks. Any WSE3.0 substitute advice.

Comment: Yes, WCF. WSE shouldn't be used unless there is no other choice. And I'm including changing jobs as one of the choices.